# import statement formatting when directly running different files in a library

Tags: python-3.x, import

I have a library that I'm working on. This isn't exactly what I have, but a good example of the structure is as follows.

```
Root Dir/
---- Src/
-------- Camera/
------------ __init__.py
------------ Module1.py
------------ Module2.py
------------ …
-------- Database/
------------ Table/
---------------- __init__.py
---------------- Table1.py
---------------- Table2.py
---------------- …
------------ Models/
---------------- __init__.py
---------------- BaseModel.py
---------------- Model1.py
---------------- Model2.py
---------------- Models.py
---------------- …
-------- __init__.py
-------- Camera.py
---- __init__.py
---- Main.py
```

Let's start with *Main.py.* If I run it directly, everything works as I expect. Currently *Main.py* only interacts with *Database*

*Main.py*

```
from src.database.table.tabel1 import (
    insert,
    delete,
    get,
    update,
)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    param = insert("Wade Watts")
    param.write_2_file()
```

*Table1* will access the table model associated with it, *Models.py*

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from ..Models.Models import characterModel, engine
...
```

As I said, this works when I call *Main.py* directly.

However, if I call *Table1.py* directly I get an import error. Inside *Table1.py* I have already written tests for all of the functionality for that particular model. As I'm building out *Main.py* I am referencing those test statements so that the functionality of *Main.py* matches. I would like to be able to run those tests to see if the results match.

I have run the *Table1.py* file multiple ways.

- *From Root Dir*

  - python src/database/table/table1.py

    - ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
  - python -m src/database/table/table1.py

    - Relative module names not supported
- *From src/database/table*

  - python table1.py

    - ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
  - python -m table1.py

    - Relative module names not supported

I would like to be able to call my submodules from the root directory to run the scripted test statements to verify functionality as I build out the new functionality that incorporates my submodules together. What I don't want to do is have to change the import structure so that it works depending on if I'm calling it directly or as a module.

my initial thought was to set up with absolute paths, but I'm running into *ModuleNotFoundError: No module name '<module_name>'* issues instead.

How do I manage my import statements properly? Do you ever want to run a submodule on its own for testing or any other reason, or is this just me?